# How to embed app.config and hard-code its web service endpoints?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I really don't know what endpoints an bindings do in app.config, but I know that I need a standalone .exe file and no more. How can I embed that file in my exe, or how to hard-code the whole thing without using app.config.
I have a small web service which returns a string value.
My app.config file reads like follows:

`

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="APIServiceSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="APIServiceSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.example.com/APIService.asmx"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="APIServiceSoap12"
          contract="MyWebAPI.APIServiceSoap" name="APIServiceSoap12" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>`
```

And mu code begins like this:
`MyWebAPI.APIServiceSoapClient client = new MyWebAPI.APIServiceSoapClient();`
Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/configuring-wcf-services-in-code

Comment: @JayV MS documents are just fragmented and I can't wrap them up altogether. I know I should have bindings, servicehosts, endpoints, contracts and many more. Is there anywhere I could find all this stuff in one place?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling in to an `ASMX` Web Service with `SOAP 1.2` and not a WCF one, things get a little more complicated, there are quite possibly several ways to do this, but the one I have used is:

```
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement tmebe = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
tmebe.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12;

TransportBindingElement tbe = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(new BindingElement[] { tmebe, tbe });

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/TestWebService/WebService1.asmx");
using (WebService1SoapClient client = new WebService1SoapClient(binding, endpointAddress))
{
    String result = client.HelloWorld();
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```